# How to requery updated values immediately after update procedure runs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

As far as I can tell, changes made to the database by the following code to "MySite"  are immediate:

```
  public List<vcData> UpdateDisplayAndUrl(List<vcData> vcDataList)
    {
        foreach (vcData vcData in vcDataList)
        {
            _entities.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE vcData SET DisplayItem = {0}, DisplayUrl = {1} WHERE ID = {2} ", vcData.DisplayItem, vcData.DisplayUrl, vcData.ID);
        }                   
        return GetTableData();
    }
```

What I would like to do is to immediately return the newly updated records for further processing, essentially, re-query the changes that have just been made:

```
    public List<vcData> GetTableData()
    {  
        var result = (from td in _entities.vcData
                      where td.SiteID == "MySite" 
                      select td).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

In my controller code, I am trying to do something like:

```
_currentvcTickerDataList = Repository.UpdateDisplayAndUrl(vcUnupdatedDataList);
//.....do more stuff with _currentvcTickerDataList, which ought to contain updated information, should it not?
```

PROBLEM:   the `GetTableData()` method does not seem to return the updated values, only the previous (unupdated) values.

I am new to LINQ, entity framework, and MVC, so I'm pretty certain there is something fundamental that I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `MergeOption` to `OverwriteChanges` before querying. Please go through the MergeOptions explained in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx) to get a clear idea.

```
public List<vcData> GetTableData()
{
    var currentMergeOption =  _entities.vcData.MergeOption;
    _entities.vcData.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;

    var result = (from td in _entities.vcData
                  where td.SiteID == "MySite" 
                  select td).ToList();

    //revert the change
    _entities.vcData.MergeOption = currentMergeOption;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Eranga, thank you very much. That seems to have done the trick.  Thank you for the MSDN reference article.