# textbox shows old value after postback while database successfully update with new value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, sqldatasource

I have a GridView with *radiobuttonlist* template column and t*extbox* in footer. I want the radio buttons to update immediately when selected and used this tutorial to achieve the desired functionality http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=261. It works great.

When new value in textbox of footer is changed, SQL is successfully updated via SqlDataSource Update() in the TextChanged() event, BUT the old value is returned in textbox after postback. As a check, I pass new value to a label on page and that is correctly displayed as well.

I tried putting GridView1.DataBind() in Page_Load() of if(!IsPostBack) but that causes radiobuttonlist items to not stay selected when they are changed and sqldatasource is not updated.

I don't know if this is relevent but because this app is a prototype, I am currently loading a specific record in gridview after page load when user enters the MYID in a textbox and clicks a button.  Eventually the grid will load with value supplied via QueryString coming from another page.

Essentially I want the textbox to work like the radiobuttonlist...as soon as the value is changed I want the database to update and display the new value in grid/textbx after postback.   Is there something obvious I am missing?

**UPDDATE**: added radiobuttonlist selectedindexchanged event code
**UPDATE 2:** added sqldatasource
**UPDATE 3:** Solution was to update SQL database directly via custom method, removed the 2nd update query in sqldatasource. TextChanged event code updated and custom method added.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="MYID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        ShowFooter="True" > 
        <Columns> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="MYID" HeaderText="MYID" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="MYID" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocID" HeaderText="DocID" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="DocID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="ItemID" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ItemID" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item" SortExpression="Item">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Item") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate > 
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment1" runat="server" 
                    Text='Section 1 Comments' AutoPostBack="True" 
                    ontextchanged="txtComment1_TextChanged" MaxLength="1000" 
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="650px"></asp:TextBox> 
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- " >     
                    <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList AutoPostBack="True" ID="rblRating" runat="server"
                    Enabled="true" SelectedIndex='<%#Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem , "Rating"))%>' 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblRating_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">0</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>                        
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Rating" HeaderText="Rating" 
                SortExpression="Rating" ReadOnly="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="lblComments1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

**.CS:**

```
protected void UpdateComment1(int myid, string comment)
        {                                                
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr)))
        { 
        string cmdStr = "UPDATE tblComments SET Comment1 = @Comment1 WHERE MYID = @MYID";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con)))
                {  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYID", myid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment1", comment);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }
        }
       }
        }
protected void txtComment1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tbox = (TextBox)sender;
            string oldComment1 = ViewState["OldComment1"].ToString(); //value saved from PreRender()
            string newComment1 = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtComment1") as TextBox).Text;
            ViewState["Section1Comments"] = newComment1;

                if(oldComment1 != newComment1)
                {
                    //<<TODO>>update history table 
                }

            if (newComment1 != null)
            {   
             //update SQL directly via custom method                  
              UpdateComment1(Convert.ToInt32(MYID), newComment1);  
            }
            GridView1.DataBind(); 
        }

 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            RadioButtonList rbtnl = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rblRating");

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Normal) > 0) //.Edit, .Normal, .Alternate, .Selected
                {
             //check for null
                    if (rbtnl.SelectedItem != null)
                    {
                        if (rbtnl.SelectedItem.Text == "0") //if rating isn’t inserted into SQL yet, deselect all 5 radio buttons
                        {
                            rbtnl.SelectedItem.Selected = false;
                        }
                            rbtnl.SelectedValue = drv[4].ToString();
                    }
                }

                //remove extra list item 
                ListItem blank = rbtnl.Items.FindByValue("0");
                if (blank != null)
                {
                    rbtnl.Items.Remove(blank);//always remove list item at index zero
                }
            }
        }

protected void rblRating_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string rate = string.Empty;

            RadioButtonList rBtnList = (RadioButtonList)sender;
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)rBtnList.Parent.Parent;

            if (rBtnList.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                rate = rBtnList.SelectedValue;

                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Rating"].DefaultValue = rate;
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["MYID"].DefaultValue = gvr.Cells[0].Text;
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["ItemID"].DefaultValue = gvr.Cells[2].Text;
            }
            else
            {     
            }  
            SqlDataSource1.Update(); 
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

**SQL & SqlDataSource:**

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SelectSection1" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE tblDetails SET Rating = @Rating WHERE MYID =  @myid   AND ItemID = @ItemID;
    --UPDATE [tblComments]  SET [Comment1] = @Comment1 WHERE MYID =@myid; " 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" DefaultValue="0"              Name="eprid"  PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Rating" Type="Int32" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="myid" Type="Int32" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="ItemID" Type="Int32" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Comment1" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectSection1] 
    @myid int  
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

--Has Form been submitted to tblComments yet?
declare @docid int
set @docid =(select distinct d.docid    
    from dbo.tblEmployee  e 
    full outer join dbo.tblDetails d on e.MYID = d.myid
    where e.myid = @myid)

 IF  @docid is null

----if not submitted yet, fill grid with evaluation items only, set rating to NULL
 BEGIN 
 SELECT 
      @myid As MYID
      ,0 as DocID
      ,ItemID 
      ,Item
      ,0 as Rating 
      ,'' As Comment1

  FROM [EPR].[dbo].[tblItems] 

  where SectionID = 1 and Active = 1  


  END
-- if submitted (DocID exists), fill grid with evaluations items and rating
 ELSE 
  BEGIN
  SELECT  
         d.eprid   
        ,d.DocID 
        ,i.[ItemID] 
        ,i.[Item] 
        ,d.Rating
        ,c.Comment1 

  FROM [EPR].[dbo].[tblItems] i

  join tblDetails  d on i.ItemID  = d.ItemID 
  join tblComments c on  d.MYID = c.MYID

  --Competence Section  
  where i.SectionID = 1 and i.Active = 1  and d.MYID = @myid 

  END
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is included in my Updated question.  My error seems to have been placing 2 update queries in sqldatasource.  I removed one update query and created a custom method to update SQL database directly to get the textbox to update immediately on textchanged event and radiobuttonlist to update immediately when selectedindexchanged. I read that you can have 2 UPDATE queries using sqldatasource if you separate each query with semi colon, but that did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update data base and immediately get updated value but the c# code does not wait to SQL operations end. Please read this:

[How to requery updated values immediately after update procedure runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678201/how-to-requery-updated-values-immediately-after-update-procedure-runs)

I suggest you to update changed textbox code separately.

```
//after all things done:
theTextbox.Text = the_value_that_it_sended.
```

Comment: Thank you @Farzin Kanzi for taking the time to point me in the right direction.  I read up on LINQ over the weekend-I've never had a need to use it before.  Can you tell me why the update to the radiobuttonlist shows up immediately in UI/gridview upon postback but not for textbox when the code for both events is almost identical? I updated my question to include the radiobuttonlist selectedindexchanged event code.

Comment: Now i am suspicious to my answer! Please tell me what is this: `Text='Section 1 Comments'` in the text box?

Comment: Funny you should ask, just his morning I changed the text property to Text='<%#Bind("Comment1") %>' Yet even on page_Load, the database value does not populate the textbox.  I think the problem is with the SQL queries.  The select statement to fill the grid is a join of 2 tables and the query result will show the comment field by every item in the grid if there was a separate column for it. I only want it to show up once which is why I put it in the footer but I think this might be why it's misbehaving. I wonder if I need a separate sqldatasource just for the textbox?

Comment: Can I see your data source? Could you add this to the question? Did i truly understand: There is one comment for all rows? If yes why you saved this in sql table?

Comment: I added sqldatasource code. Yes, you understand correctly, unfortunately. I am trying to keep the database intact because we are porting from InfoPath to .net solution trying to use the same db.  This is a simple form with several ratings and one comment for in each section.  The comments are in their own table by MYID and DocID.   The tblEmployee always contains MYID. If tblDetails and tblComments does not have a MyID and/or DocID that's indicator the forms' ratings are not "submitted" yet.  Maybe I should put the comments in a freeform outside of gridview and handle it separately?

Comment: The first update parameter of sqlDataSource1 is data type `int32` : `<asp:Parameter Name="Rating" Type="Int32" /> ` So what is this: `SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters[0].DefaultValue = "True";` ?

Comment: Sorry, that's me blindly following the tutorial I referenced.  I've since commented-out those lines of code but the same behavior persists.  I will update code in the question.  I also noticed the type was missing from the Comments, I added it but still no change.